# Python - Pandas replacing dataframe column values - column data stored as list (i.e., '[this, that,'])

Tags: python, pandas, list, text, replace

I've tried a bunch of different things and I'm assuming I'm close here.  I have a list of words that I generated from research abstracts courtesy of the Gensim keyword summarizer.  The data is accurate, however it's stored as a list for each row and I want to get rid of the [' and '] for each row.  I tried the code below and different variations, but either I get an error or the code processes but doesn't replace. I've tried:

```
 #scenario 1
 keywords = ['screened', 'model', 'health',  'volume']
 df['newnlpkeywords'] = keywords
 df['newnlpkeywords'].replace("']", "", inplace=True)
```

and

```
 #scenario 2

 keywords = ['screened', 'model', 'health',  'volume']
 df['newnlpkeywords'] = keywords.replace(replace("']", "")
```

I knew it's a noob question, but I'm trying to learn! I figure after 30 minutes of attempts, I should ask for help.  Thanks!

Comment: what output do you get and what output would you like to get?

Comment: Assuming `newnlpkeywords` is a `list` and not a `str` type with brackets in it, you can do `df["newnlpkeywords"] = df["newnlpkeywords"].apply(lambda x: ", ".join(x))`. If the variable is a `str` type, then you should be able to do `df["newnlpkeywords"].str.replace(r"\[|\]", "")`

Comment: My output is literally the list, as in ['screened', 'model', 'health',  'volume']

Comment: @brittenb - that worked, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for

```py
import numpy as np
import re

rgx = lambda x: re.sub("']","",x)

rgx = np.vectorize(rgx)

df['newnlpkeywords'].values = rgx(df['newnlpkeywords'].values)
```

The following code applies the rgx function to every row in df['newnlpkeywords']

(I know there are probably more pythonic ways to do this however this is a quick fix, I'm sure there's a tidier answer)